# How to create index for Column Table in SAP HANA?

Tags: hana

I have a little problem in create a index for a column table in HANA.
I need to create index and the value maybe could be null.

In Oracle SQL I create like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE (NVL(MY_COLUMN,' '));
```

But in HANA, I don't know what can replace the `NVL` function.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the NVL function in HANA. An index does not have to be "NOT NULL".
So in your case, you would create an index simply by executing the following query:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN);
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaone/helpdata/en/20/d44b4175191014a940afff4b47c7ea/content.htm) for more information.